# How do I pull multiple values from html page using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm performing some data analysis for my own knowledge from nhl spread/betting odds information. I'm able to pull some information, but Not the entire data set. I want to pull the list of games and the associated into a panda dataframe, but I have been able to perform the proper loop around the html tags. I've tried the `findAll` option and the xpath route. I'm not successful with either.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://www.thespread.com/nhl-hockey-public-betting-chart'

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)

# here, we fetch the content from the url, using the requests library
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")


# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = page_content.find('div', attrs={'class': 'datarow'})
name = name_box.text.strip()

print (name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script goes through each datarow and pulls out each item individually and then appends them into a pandas DataFrame.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page_link = 'https://www.thespread.com/nhl-hockey-public-betting-chart'

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)

# here, we fetch the content from the url, using the requests library
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")


# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
tables = page_content.find_all('div', class_='datarow')

# Iterate through rows
rows = []

# Iterate through each datarow and pull out each home/away separately
for table in tables:
    # Get time and date
    time_and_date_tag = table.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "time"})[0].contents
    date = time_and_date_tag[1]
    time = time_and_date_tag[-1]
    # Get teams
    teams_tag = table.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "datacell teams"})[0].contents[-1].contents
    home_team = teams_tag[1].text
    away_team = teams_tag[-1].text
    # Get opening
    opening_tag = table.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "child-open"})[0].contents
    home_open_value = opening_tag[1]
    away_open_value = opening_tag[-1]
    # Get current
    current_tag = table.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "child-current"})[0].contents
    home_current_value = current_tag[1]
    away_current_value = current_tag[-1]
    # Create list
    rows.append([time, date, home_team, away_team,
                 home_open_value, away_open_value,
                 home_current_value, away_current_value])

columns = ['time', 'date', 'home_team', 'away_team',
           'home_open', 'away_open',
           'home_current', 'away_current']

print(pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns))
```

Comment: Awesome job, So you are pulling the large data set called data row, then found each tag within one row and iterated thru?

Comment: Indeed, this is generally much easier when the table is actually a html table rather than nested divs.where each item is required to be pulled out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your question.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://www.thespread.com/nhl-hockey-public-betting-chart'

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)

# here, we fetch the content from the url, using the requests library
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")


for cell in page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'datarow'}):
    name = cell.text.strip()
    print (name)
```