# Grabbing Data from Web Page using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, data-analysis

I'm performing the same web scraping pattern that I just learned from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018417/how-do-i-pull-multiple-values-from-html-page-using-python/53018749#53018749) , however, I'm unable to scrap the using below script. I keep getting an empty return and I know the tags are there. I want to find_all "mubox" then pulls values for O/U and goalie information. This so weird, what am I missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page_link = 'https://www.thespread.com/nhl-scores-matchups'

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=10)

# here, we fetch the content from the url, using the requests library
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
tables = page_content.find_all("div", class_="mubox")

print (tables)

# Iterate through rows
rows = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses an internal API before rendering the data. This api is an xml file, you can get [here](https://www.thespread.com/matchups/NHL/matchup-list_20181030.xml) which contains all the match information. You can parse it using beautiful soup :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://www.thespread.com/matchups/NHL/matchup-list_20181030.xml'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=10)
body = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "lxml")

data = [
    (
        t.find("road").text, 
        t.find("roadgoalie").text, 
        t.find("home").text,
        t.find("homegoalie").text,
        float(t.find("ot").text),
        float(t.find("otmoney").text),
        float(t.find("ft").text),
        float(t.find("ftmoney").text)
    )
    for t in body.find_all('event')
]

print(data)
```

Comment: This is a great technique. I have a couple questions related. Did you use developer tools to find the api? How do I move up and down the tags? For example, I want to start at <Matchup> then move down to <Road><TeamInfo><Team>.text.